# Custom UICollectionViewLayout header and storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've created a `UICollectionViewController` in storyboard along with a header for the collection view.

I'm using a third party `UICollectionViewLayout` called `CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout`. When `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:)` is called for a header, `kind` is `CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader` instead of `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` and the program crashes and tells me I didn't register a class for `CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader`. Makes sense. But if I programmatically register a class for `CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader`, I don't get the benefit of my work with storyboard because the program would call `initWithFrame:` when initializing the header instead of `initWithCoder`.

Is there any way to get around this issue where I can somehow use what I've created in storyboard for `CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader`?

Comment: I wrote it in swift but lemme know if there's a huge difference in terms of implementation (not syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar issue today and found out that I had to change my header cell registration from:

```
collectionView.registerClass(
    UICollectionReusableView.self,
    forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,     
    withReuseIdentifier: headerId
)
```

to

```
collectionView.registerClass(
    UICollectionReusableView.self, 
    forSupplementaryViewOfKind: layout.CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader, 
    withReuseIdentifier: headerId
)
```

Hope this is helpful, I have been hitting my head against a wall for a couple of hours, and I only found your question when search for help myself.

**Note**: layout was defined above like this `let layout = CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout()`

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. Yeah you would need to register `CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader` in order for it to run. However, my header is already designed in storyboard and if I programmatically register the class like what you're doing, `initWithFrame` is called instead of `initWithCoder`. `initWithFrame` doesn't look at what's been designed in storyboard, unfortunately...

Comment: No problemo. Thanks for trying.